# Returning a Result Set With Two Different Values

Tags: mysql

I have two columns: `user_id` and `gift_id`. I'm looking to return a result set where `user_id` = 15906 or where `gift_id` = 15906, **but not** where `user_id` = `gift_id`.

So out of the following data I should get two records.

```
user_id | gift_id
--------------------------
15906 | null
15906 | 15906
12345 | 15906
```

I want the first and last record of that set and not the one where `user_id` and `gift_id`match.

Comment: I think the null value in the 1st row is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above SQL statements is that they do not take into account that the SQL statement is comparing type int to type NULL... most sql parser don't really like this.

Try xQbert's code but using the [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function

```
Select user_ID, Gift_ID
FROM table
WHERE (user_ID = 15906 or gift_ID=15906) and (user_ID <> coalesce(gift_id,0))
```

This will make it so any NULL is converted to 0 for proper comparisions.

Comment: Many thanks for a good answer and explanation of why I had the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select user_ID, Gift_ID
FROM table
WHERE (user_ID = 15906 or gift_ID=15906) and (user_ID <> gift_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most natural fit seems a `xor`

```
select user_id, gift_id 
from table1 
where (coalesce(user_id,0) = 15906) xor (coalesce(gift_id,0) = 15906)
```

A [link, just in case.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using group in where cause solve problem :

```
select * FROM tablename where ( user_id = 15906 or gift_id = 15906 ) and gift_id <> user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE ( user_id = 15906 or gift_id = 15906 ) and gift_id <> user_id;
```